# Copiar y reemplazar una tabla de una instancia sql a otra

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Buen día! Estoy algo trabado con esta situación:
Mi sistema trabaja con determinadas tablas que copio exactamente de otro sistema (otro servidor SQL). Actualmente lo hago de forma manual (comparo los registros que se modificaron en determinada fecha y los reemplazo en mi tabla y agrego si hay nuevos).

Lo que necesito es hacer un script para que a determinada hora del dia haga un reemplazo completo de la tabla origen a destino, sin importar los datos existentes. (aclaracion: se hace a través de una VPN)
Supongo que primero es un drop de mi tabla pero es algo que tambien quiero evitar, ya que si se produce un corte a la mitad de la transferencia me quedaria sin datos.

Estuve leyendo varias formas de hacerlo, (https://www.sqlshack.com/es/como-copiar-tablas-de-una-base-de-datos-otra-en-sql-server/) pero en todas lo que hace es una copia cuando todavia no existe la tabla en la instancia de destino

Desde ya muchas gracias de antemano.